# Can I fix Snow Leopard Server DNS without re-installing the OS?

Tags: domain-name-system, osx-snow-leopard

The DNS GUI in Server Admin stopped working, so I deleted everything from /etc/dns and /var/named and I think another directory too assuming Server Admin would regenerate them. Nope. I ran the Server Essentials package from the OS disc, and that made it so I could edit forwarders, but I still can't save any zones through the GUI.

Comment: Ouch. A good policy is, rather than delete current configs, move them to a .orig directory (or the equivalent).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit of a hassle, but you could always install OS X Server on another Mac (or another partition on your server) and grab the missing folders from there.  You might also be able to extract the files directly from the installer packages on the DVD with [Pacifist](http://www.charlessoft.com/), but I think at least some are created during the initial setup (probably why reinstalling the essentials package didn't do it).

Comment: It's probably not kosher for someone to just post them, is it?

Comment: I used Pacifist. I searched for "named" and restored that directory, and then searched for named.conf and restored that. I couldn't find the contents of /etc/dns anywhere, but the server admin is working now!